# Al renderizar un componente no muestra la nueva información del componente dependiendo del parametro enviado

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy utilizando react js y como base de datos utilizo firebase de google
Este es mi componente Show (al cual le paso el parametro "name", dependiendo si name vale "products" o "rooms" debo pasarlo como parametro al componente Table, pero al hacerle un console.log (lineas 89 - 90) siempre me muestra el objeto products, a pesar de haber mandado a imprimir el objeto rooms en la consola, imprime el objeto products.

No encuentro el error, si alguien pudiera apoyarme por favor

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
import { collection, getDocs, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebaseConfig/firebase";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import withReactContent from "sweetalert2-react-content";

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

const Show = ({ name }) => {
  //1 - configuramos los hooks
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

  //2 - referenciamos a la DB firestore
  const Collection = collection(db, name);

  //3 - Funcion para mostrar TODOS los docs
  const getItemsProducts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(Collection);
    //console.log(data.docs)
    setProducts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    console.log(products);
  };

  const getItemsRooms = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(Collection);
    setRooms(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    console.log(rooms);
  };

  //4 - Funcion para eliminar un doc

  const deleteItemProducts = async (id) => {
    const itemDoc = doc(db, name, id);
    await deleteDoc(itemDoc);
    getItemsProducts();
  };

  const deleteItemRooms = async (id) => {
    const itemDoc = doc(db, name, id);
    await deleteDoc(itemDoc);
    getItemsRooms();
  };

 
  //6 - usamos useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    getItemsProducts();

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getItemsRooms();

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  //7 - devolvemos vista de nuestro componente
  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <div>{name}</div>
      {console.log(products)}
      {console.log(rooms)}
      <Table
        confirmDelete={confirmDelete}
        name={name}
        data={name === "products" ? products : rooms}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Show;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estás utilizando dos arreglos distintos para almacenar los productos y las habitaciones, y en tu componente `Table` siempre estás pasando el arreglo `products`, independientemente de si `name` es "products" o "rooms".

Una forma de solucionarlo sería utilizar un único arreglo y cambiar su contenido dependiendo del valor de `name`. Por ejemplo:

```
const Show = ({ name }) => {
  //1 - configuramos los hooks
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  //2 - referenciamos a la DB firestore
  const Collection = collection(db, name);

  //3 - Funcion para mostrar TODOS los docs
  const getItems = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(Collection);
    setItems(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  //4 - Funcion para eliminar un doc
  const deleteItem = async (id) => {
    const itemDoc = doc(db, name, id);
    await deleteDoc(itemDoc);
    getItems();
  };

  //6 - usamos useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  //7 - devolvemos vista de nuestro componente
  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <div>{name}</div>
      <Table confirmDelete={confirmDelete} name={name} data={items} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Otra forma de hacerlo sería utilizar un único hook `useEffect` y, dentro de su función de efecto, realizar la carga de los items dependiendo del valor de `name`. Algo así:

```
const Show = ({ name }) => {
  //1 - configuramos los hooks
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  //2 - referenciamos a la DB firestore
  const Collection = collection(db, name);

  //3 - Funcion para mostrar TODOS los docs
  const getItems = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(Collection);
    setItems(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  //4 - Funcion para eliminar un doc
  const deleteItem = async (id) => {
    const itemDoc = doc(db, name, id);
    await deleteDoc(itemDoc);
    getItems();
  };

  //6 - usamos useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [name]);

  //7 - devolvemos vista de nuestro componente
  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <div>{name}</div>
      <Table confirmDelete={confirmDelete} name={name} data={items} />
    </>
  );
};
```

De esta forma, cada vez que cambie el valor de `name`, se llamará a la función `getItems()` para cargar los items correspondientes.

Espero te ayude de algo, o al menos te guie. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me sirvio la ultima forma!